# Android: Show 2 TextViews horizontally in each row of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm creating a custom ArrayAdapter in order to show more than 1 TextView in a ListView ([Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)). My aim is to show them in a table-like format (with 2 columns), kind of like this:

```
A     B
----------
C     D
----------
E     F
```

However, I keep getting them in a vertical format, like this:

```
A    
B
----------
C     
D
----------
E     
F
```

Here is my xml for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>   

<TextView android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>           

 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not too familiar with **fill_parent** and **wrap_content**, maybe I'm doing something wrong with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
  android:orientation="vertical"
```

To

```
  android:orientation="horizontal"
```

And use margin's for spacing between the views. Also make the below changes

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Edit:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>   

<TextView android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>           

 </LinearLayout>
```

snap

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm! The android:layout_marginLeft did the trick.

Comment: Is there a way to make the second column at an absolute distance from the left margin? Right now it's 30dp from the first column, right?

Edit: Just found out, I need to set android:width of the first TextView

Comment: @Karan yes you can specify the margin as you would like. Or use a relative layout to place 2nd textview realtive to the first textview.

Answer (score 2):

you have put android:orientation="vertical" in your row layout. make it "horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

//Change your layout as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>   

<TextView android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>           

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` will make the textview take the full space.